# SQL UPDATE not updating my tables

Tags: php, sql

This is my current code

```
$reg = $_REQUEST['reg'];
$vin_no = $_REQUEST['vin_no'];
$imei = $_REQUEST['imei'];

$sql="UPDATE client SET 
        reg = '$reg',
        imei = '$imei',
        vin_no = '$vin_no'
WHERE imei = '$imei'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

IMEI is already completed with previous data thus it not supposed to change. The other columns are empty, Will UPDATE be the correct method in this instance. As currently when I send the information from the form page it doesn't update the SQL table at all. I use POST on my form and I do get the data from the form.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: echo the `$sql` and execute it in phpmyadmin. that shoudl show you any errors in it.

Comment: And [display errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) if you want to know what is the error.

Comment: Too many unknowns. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `mysql_query() or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: `$var = !empty($_REQUEST['var']) ? $_REQUEST['var'] : "It's empty";` and/or your query failed.

Comment: Would be useful to see your HTML form.

Comment: and use `mysql_affected_rows()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php for *trueness*, the real one.

Comment: *"Will UPDATE be the correct method in this instance."* - sounds like a *"will this work?"* type of question. Who knows.... try it, check for errors.

Comment: You're going to have let everyone know what's going on here Trevor. Riggs provided you with an answer below. We have no way of knowing where we are with this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the only problem with the code, but to answer what I think you are asking...

If you dont want to change the IMEI field as part of the UPDATE, then just dont put it in the list of fields to be updated you only need to update the columns that you are actually changing, like so

I have also added some basic debug suggestions, of course if you are on a development server than you should have error reporting on anyway, but just in case you do not or are working on the LIVE server...

```
// force some error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$reg = $_REQUEST['reg'];
$vin_no = $_REQUEST['vin_no'];
$imei = $_REQUEST['imei'];

$sql="UPDATE client SET 
        reg = '$reg',
        vin_no = '$vin_no'
WHERE imei = '$imei'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// test the result of the update, show the error if it fails
if ( ! $result ) {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: we can update and use a column name in where at same time.

Comment: But it does not actually make a lot of sence to do that though

Comment: Not in that particular case. But if I want to fix a typo, I might want to update the name of all lines having a particular name (with a mistake in it).

Comment: See the question _IMEI is already completed with previous data thus it not supposed to change_